# Make linux kernel function show in ftrace available_filter_function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ftrace

I want to trace [perf_event_open](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/events/core.c#L3347) using ftrace but it does not show in available_filter_function. In fact, it seems that only functions loaded in modules are shown.

Is there a default blacklist for non-module functions? how to add the function I need?

Comment: What is your OS distribution? What is exact name (version) of linux kernel (output of `uname -a`)

Answer (score 2):

There is some info in "Secrets of the Ftrace function tracer" article, January 20, 2010 by Steven Rostedt: https://lwn.net/Articles/370423/

> A list of functions that can be added to the filter files is shown in the `available_filter_functions` file. This list of functions was derived from the list of stored `mcount` callers previously mentioned.

Set of functions listed in the file depends on kernel compilation options (please check them in /boot/config* or in /proc/config.gz and add result to the question):

```
CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE
CONFIG_FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER
```

There is more info about mcount in earlier article of series: https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/ Debugging the kernel using Ftrace - part 1, December 2009, Steven Rostedt:

> One of the most powerful tracers of Ftrace is the function tracer. It uses the -pg option of gcc to have every function in the kernel call a special function "mcount()" .. When CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE is configured the call is converted to a NOP at boot time to keep the system running at 100% performance. During compilation the mcount() call-sites are recorded.

Can you also check files in  /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_perf_event_open/ ?

Syscalls are available to ftrace not as functions, but as events (example from opensourceforu.com/2010/12/kernel-tracing-with-ftrace-part-2/):

```
trace-cmd record -e syscalls ls  ##Initiate tracing on the syscall 'ls'
##(A file called trace.dat gets created in the current directory.)
trace-cmd report                 ## displays the report from trace.dat
```

For me `trace-cmd record -e syscalls perf stat ls -d .` catches calls to `perf_event_open`.